# Socket.io trigger event from controller of HTTP API

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

In my Node+Express server app I'd like to emit notifications from specific controllers triggered by requests coming from the HTTP API:

For example:

```
router.route('/status').put(Order.changeStatus)

class Order {
  static changeStatus(req, res) {
    // Modifying database record with changed status
    // Emiting message to specific socket room
  }
}
```

I'm handling socket connections as follows:

```
import AuthMiddleware from '../middleware/AuthMiddleware';

const socketio = require('socket.io');
let io;

module.exports.listen = function(app){
  io = socketio.listen(app);

  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Client connected');

    AuthMiddleware.authenticateSocket(socket, (err, user) => {
      socket.join(user._id);
      console.log('Client joined to: ' + user._id);
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('Client disconnected')
    });
  });

  return io;
}
```

After authenticating the incoming socket connection, it is subscribed to the room of its own ID.

The socket is initialised at the top of the project as follows:

```
import app from './app';
import http from 'http';


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 7235;
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('./socket/main').listen(server);

// App start
server.listen(PORT, err => {
  console.log(err || `Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Although I'm able to process incoming events and respond to those, the problem with this structure is that I can't access the io object within the controllers to be able to emit data in a particular room as follows:

```
io.sockets.in(userID).emit('notification', data);
```

**What would be the proper structure that enables to trigger socket events from the controllers of the HTTP API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controllers need to have access to the configured io object.  The easiest way to do that is to export it in your module instead of just exporting the listen function, perhaps like so:

```
import AuthMiddleware from '../middleware/AuthMiddleware';

const socketio = require('socket.io');
let io;

function listen(app){
  io = socketio.listen(app);

  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Client connected');

    AuthMiddleware.authenticateSocket(socket, (err, user) => {
      socket.join(user._id);
      console.log('Client joined to: ' + user._id);
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('Client disconnected')
    });
  });

  return io;
}

module.exports = {
  listen, io
}
```

Then your controllers can just do `const io = require('./path/to/that').io;`